# Artifactory API to upload directory with contents

Tags: rest, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I was looking into the [Artifactory REST API doc](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API) but I could not find any API that allows us to upload a directory with contents (can be files, subdirectory). There is only API to upload an individual file. I also found [this](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-upload-a-folder-with-its-content-to-artifactory/) where it stated that it can be done through GUI or the JFrog CLI. I wonder if I misread some documents and if there actually is a way to do that with the REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to upload (a.k.a "deploy") a directory with its contents via REST API you can use the [Deploy Artifacts from Archive](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactsfromArchive) endpoint.

You'll need to create an archive file (`zip`, `tar`, `tar.gz`) with the directory and its contents, and call the upload API with the target folder, specifying the `X-Explode-Archive: true` request header.

E.g. (simplified - omitted auth, etc.):

```
curl -X PUT https://jfrog.foo.bar/artifactory/my-repo-local/   \
     -H "X-Explode-Archive: true"                              \
     -T my-file.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. I hope it also works for nested directory case

Comment: This does not delete any other files in the archive if they exist in current destination but not source archive